# Resolving file independently from where bash script is run

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a very simple script reading a text file which is in a different directory:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a urls < ../dat/urls.txt
```

This works fine when running the script from the directory the script is in e.g) .`/fetch_urls`

But if I run the script from the say the user home or via cron it fails to resolve the urls.txt file. e.g.

```
/home/my-user/data-transfer/fetch_urls.sh
```

It fails with:

```
line 3: ../dat/urls.txt: No such file or directory
```

Is there some way to make it work so it always resolves correctly the urls.txt file. Or maybe I have to pass the location of urls.txt as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is relative to the directory of your script. You can get it with:

```
script_dir=$(dirname "$0")
```

You now have two solutions:

- Either `cd` to that directory before accessing `urls.txt`. I personally don't do this as it may break other relative paths (e.g. paths given on the command line)
- Or, better, prefix your relative paths with that directory:

  ```
  IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a urls < "$script_dir/../dat/urls.txt"
  ```

Comment: Great. Many thanks. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to resolve the `current directory` of the launched script (`fetch_urls.sh` in your example).

```
myPath=$( which $0 )
currentDir=$( dirname "$myPath" )
```

Then, you simply have to fix your line in your script:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a urls < "$currentDir/../dat/urls.txt"
```